# add xmlElement into a XmlNode

Tags: c#, xmldocument

How to add an element into a XmlNode.

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
XmlNode nodes = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/configuration/schedulers");
```

XML Example:

```
<schedulers>
<Scheduler name="test1" alert="4" timerType="type1" cronExpression="0/10 * * * * ?">
  <property name="customerName" value="customerA" />
</Scheduler>
<Scheduler name="test2" alert="3" timerType="type2" cronExpression="0/15 * * * * ?" />
<Scheduler name="test3" maxFailureAlert="3" timerType="Type3" cronExpression="0/20 * * * * ?" />
```

And I want to add new scheduler

```
<schedulers>
  <Scheduler name="test1" alert="4" timerType="type1" cronExpression="0/10 * * * * ?">
    <property name="customerName" value="COMMON_MODEL" />
  </Scheduler>
  <Scheduler name="test2" alert="3" timerType="type2" cronExpression="0/15 * * * * ?" />
  <Scheduler name="test3" maxFailureAlert="3" timerType="Type3" cronExpression="0/20 * * * * ?" />
  <Scheduler name="test4" maxFailureAlert="3" timerType="Type3" cronExpression="0/50 * * * * ?" />
</schedulers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `XmlDocument.CreateElement` method to create an element:

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
XmlNode nodes = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/configuration/schedulers");

var newElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Scheduler");
```

Then, you can set any attributes using `SetAttribute`:

```
newElement.SetAttribute("name", "test4"); 
newElement.SetAttribute("maxFailureAlert", "3"); 
newElement.SetAttribute("timerType", "Type3"); 
newElement.SetAttribute("cronExpression", "0/50 * * * * ?");
```

And append a new element to your existing one:

```
nodes.AppendChild(newElement);
```

Don't forget to save a document:

```
xmlDoc.Save(filePath);
```

Comment: how to set if I have multiple attributes in a element?
<Scheduler name="test2" alert="3" timerType="type2" cronExpression="0/15 * * * * ?" />